# What does all the stuff in Firebase Spark free plan mean?

Tags: firebase, web, hosting, web-hosting, firebase-hosting

So I want to host a personal website that is created on Angular which uses Node.JS and I wanted find a good place to host it.

I was thinking of using Firebase but I don't understand what it means by

- 100 simultaneous connection (realtime database)
- 10 GB/month download (realtime database)
- 10 GB/month bandwidth (cloud firestore)
- document writes,reads, and deletes (cloud firestore)
- 10 GB/month transferred (hosting)

Also, I want to know from the community if this is enough for a personal website? I already have a custom domain.

[Firebase Info](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/)

Comment: You might want to take questions like this to firebase-talk instead of Stack Overflow.  SO is for programming question.  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/firebase-talk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on the amount of traffic to your website, if you're not expecting hundreds of visitors a day then this is definitely enough, that's if your website even uses a database, it means it can accept 100 connections (more simply 100 people) connecting to it at the same time.

In short; this is enough for a personal website.